# An application of Poincare inequality [solved]

Tags: partial-differential-equations, functional-inequalities

I am woking on Evans PDE problem 5.10. #15: Fix $\alpha>0$ and let $U=B^0(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Show there exists a constant $C$ depending only on $n$ and $\alpha$ such that
$$
\int_U u^2 dx \le C\int_U|Du|^2 dx, 
$$
provided that $u\in W^{1,1}(U)$ satisfies
$$
|\{x\in U\ |\ u(x)=0\}|>\alpha. 
$$
I would appreciate your helping me with this problem.

Comment: Try Poincare's inequality.

Comment: I know it will be probably proved by Poincare inequality but don't know how to use the assumption on $u$.

Comment: I changed the title so that people can understand what I am looking for.

Comment: I misunderstood something and this can be easily solved. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Yeah. That happens! You are welcome.

Comment: I am working on this problem too and would like to see how to prove this. In 1 dimensional case, one can bound the left hand side by derivative and I naively hope this works in general dimension with appropriate modification.